# How to change Windows DFS replication log file path?

Tags: windows-server-2003, logging, dfs

I have enabled DFS replication for a couple shares on my Windows Server 2003 machine and it works fine, except that I would like the debug logs to be written to a different drive (it logs in to the windows folder on the C drive by default) and also change the logging levels so it's not logging as much.

I found some information [here at technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/04/02/directory-services-debug-logging-primer.aspx) (see the section titled DFS replication) and a couple other sites with similar information.

The problem is, I do not have the registry keys (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dfsr\Parameters)  - I do not have the "Dfsr" container.   Also, if I try the wmi command (wmic /namespace:\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrmachineconfig set debuglogseverity=5) it says invalid namespace 0x8004100e.

I do have a "dfs" container at that registry path (dfs instead of dfsr) and \Parameters, but none of the registry keys mentioned on that technet site.

How can I change the path and/or log level?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its using DFSR? DFSR is only available on Windows Server 2003 R2 onwards and only if replication is configured using the new management console. It sounds like you have FRS in use.